# i have three buttons in a one layout and i want to show diffrent view

Tags: android, button, view

i have three buttons in a one layout and i want to show diffrent views with diffrent texts under these buttons, every button clicked shows diffrent view, i know that i have to use OnClickListner to show these views but how can i create these views ?

the first and the second views are  a webview that shows data from a web source but the third view is a textview that i coudn't use to show its data.

` iv4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            wv.loadData( details , "text/html", "utf-8");
                        }
                      });'

```
             iv5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
         wv.loadData("Name :" + name + " / " + "Adresse :" + adress + " / " + "Tél :" + phone, "text/html", "utf-8");
                    }
                  }); `
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3); 

            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
            b2.setOnClickListener(this);
            b3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then **implements OnClickListener** on you class and you get `onClick`method

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
                         //click for b1
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
                         //click for b2
            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
                         //click for b3
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//  In XML


<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickButton1"
        android:text="Button 1"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickButton2"
        android:text="Button 2"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickButton3"
        android:text="Button 3"/>
```

//Now in Java make method

```
public void clickButton1(View view){
// your work may be Intent
 startActivity(new Intent(this, DestinationFile.class));
}
public void clickButton2(View view){
// your work may be Intent
}
public void clickButton3(View view){
// your work may be Intent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a web View, then create a WebView in XML:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In Java use:

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
web.loadUrl("https://www.wikipedia.org/"); // your URL
```